# getting an error related to react hook useHistory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I have implemented useHistory() same as i implemented below , previously i didnt get any error but in this compmonent i am getting an error as

> Line 6:18:  React Hook "useHistory" is called in function "showPost" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

```
import React from 'react';
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';

const showPost = () =>{
    let history = useHistory();

    const closeUpload = () =>{
        history.goBack();
    }

    return(
        <div className="overlay">
            <div className="overlay-container">
                <button className="close-btn" onClick = {closeUpload}><CloseIcon color="action"/></button>
                <h1>Hello</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default showPost;
```

please, help me in solving this.
thank you in advance.

Comment: Good day.  What version of React and React Router are you using? You need React 16.8+ and React Router 5.1 to 6.0 ( useHistory() does not work before 5.1 or after 6.0).

Answer (score 5):

You should allways call your React component with Capital letter.

**UPD:** 
From https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#rendering-a-component

Note: Always start component names with a capital letter.
React treats components starting with lowercase letters as DOM tags. For example,  represents an HTML div tag, but  represents a component and requires Welcome to be in scope.

Answer (score 2):

https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#html-tags-vs.-react-components

Just capitalize the component

```
const showPost
```

To

```
const ShowPost
```

Do as well as for the

```
export default showPost
```

To

```
export default ShowPost
```